# synchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value in typeORM transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, nestjs, typeorm

I am using Typeform to store value multiple tables in my DB. But after saving my value it's the return Promise {  } instead of a value.
This is my function. I follow the most similar question link in StackOverflow to understand my problem. But non of that methods is not working for me...I really need your help. Thank you very much.

```
 async create(orderData: CreateOrderDto): Promise<any> {
    const orderModel: {
      created_date: Date;
      status: string;
      customer: Customer;
    } = {
      status: orderData.status,
      created_date: orderData.created_date,
      customer: orderData.customer,
    };

    try {
      await this.entityManager.transaction(
        async (entityManager: EntityManager) => {
          const order = await entityManager
            .getRepository(Order)
            .save(orderModel);
          if (order) {
            orderData.order_details.map(async (item) => {
              await entityManager
                .getRepository(OrderHasItem)
                .save({
                  order_id: order.id,
                  item_id: item.item_id,
                  unit_price: item.unit_price,
                  qty: item.qty,
                })
                .then((item) => {
                  console.log('item', item);
                  return item;
                });
            });
          }
        },
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new BadRequestException('There is an error');
    }
  }
```

Comment: It says `async create` why would you claim it's synchronous? Moreover, its declaration says it returns `Promise<any>`. I don't really see a problem here - an async function returns a promise, which is what all async functions do.

Comment: @ VLAZ Can you please explain a little bit more..?

Comment: Async functions *cannot* return a value directly. That's the reason they are async. They instead return a promise which *eventually* will give you the value. That's what a promise is - a notification mechanism for tasks, that tells you whether what the task produced. Promises naturally go with async functions because async means something *will not happen now* - not synchronously. Therefore, async functions would always produce a promise, If you order a pizza, somebody has to make it and deliver it to you. That's an async task. You can do other stuff while waiting.